# fckeditor doesn't show in safari

Tags: php, javascript, fckeditor

I have a problem with fckeditor, it shows in all the browsers but doesn't show in safari. Does anybody have a solution?

Comment: Do you have any code to show us?

Comment: And error messages? There are bound to be error messages in the console.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you've turned off javascript in your safari?

Answer (score 1):

Ah.  Older versions of fckeditor (before version 2 or so) don't work in Safari.  Look for a newer version of it from their site. Or you can use the newer "ckeditor" that fckeditor has become.  You can find older versions still though.  Version 2.6.4.1 works fine in Safari.